# Linear Search Python

Tags: python, function, binary-search, linear-search

I am new to python and we were given an assignment to create a linear search program that does not use "in" or index. The program compiles but says that every number I input is not in the list. I also have to do the same thing for a binary search but I'm doing things one at a time ha. Any help is appreciated!

PS: How could I show what index it is in without using the "index" function?

```
def linearSearch(intList,target):
    found = False
    position = 0
    while position < len(intList) and not found:
        if intList[position] == target:
            found = True
        position = position + 1

    return found

linearList = [3,5,9,7,6,12,15,9,1]
numInput = input("What number are you looking for? ")
numFound = linearSearch(linearList, numInput)
if numFound:
    print("The number is in index: ")
else:
    print("The number is not in the list")
```

Comment: Here is a hint to fix your problem: The input is string type, and you are comparing it with integer

Answer (score 1):

1) Start `position = -1`

2) `return position`

3) You want to `position+=1` before `if intList[position] == target:` and you want to `break` when you do find the element. You then don't need `found`

Something is found when `linearSearch(linearList, numInput) > 0`

Then, your code just doesn't work because the list contains ints whereas `input` will always return a string. You must use `int(input(".."))`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I immediately corrected the input from being string to integer right after posting. I am getting an error from the while loop " while position < len(intList) and not found:" says object of type int has no len().

Comment: You've assigned `intList` to just an int somehow. Debug your code, on your own, please

Comment: Hint: Your parameter order is 1) list 2) number to find

Answer (score 1):

This method uses list comprehension, and it will account for any duplicates in the list as well. It assigns a list of index/indices where the key occurs in the list. Read more about list comprehension [here.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6]
el = 4
search = [i for i in range(len(l)) if el==l[i]]
print(search)
```

output:

```
[3, 4]
```

alternatively,

```
def LinSearch(target, intList):
     search = [i for i in range(len(intList)) if target==intList[i]]
     return search
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def linearSearch(intList,target):
    #print (target)
    found = False
    position = 0
    while position < len(intList):
        #print(intList[position])
        if intList[position] == target:
            found = True
            break
        position = position + 1

    return found

linearList = [3,5,9,7,6,12,15,9,1]
numInput = int(input("What number are you looking for? "))
numFound = linearSearch(linearList,numInput)
if numFound:
    print("The number is in index: ")
else:
    print("The number is not in the list")
```

Please take care of type conversion...

Answer (score 0):

**Linear Search :**

```
 // funtion which rturns true if item found inside list.
    def linearSearch(list, value):
            for i in range(len(list)):
                if i == value:
                     return True
```

// Call above function pass list of values and item to search

```
    list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    item = 10
    print(linearSearch(list, item)) // item to search
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def target(list,num):

    for x in list:
        if x == str(num):
            print("match found:"+x)
            break
    else:
         print('no match found')


list1 = ['6','4','7','9','0','2','3','1']
inp = input('Enter number to search:')
target(list1,inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def linear_search(list, key):

    for i, item in enumerate(list):
        if item == key:
            return i
    return -1

print(linear_search([4,5,2,7,1,8],7))

#If key is in the list returns its position in the list, otherwise returns -1.
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO. Explanations add long term value, helps impart information and learning distinct from services), and keeps SO quality high. Future visitors should be able to learn & impart this to their own coding issues. Please consider editing to highlight features of your solution that address the OP's issue,  explaining why it is useful or why you choose that approach, or provide insight that the OP missed. Especially for homework questions, where the point is for learning. Sometimes including a link to source documentation for an introduced functions is beneficial

Answer (score 0):

```
 n=int(input("Enter the number:"))
 list,n=[10,11,12,13,14,15],n
 if n in list:
     print("Element found at",list.index(n))
 else:
     print("Not Found")
```

**Advice**: In python index starts from 0. To start from 1 format the code like this: `list.index(n)+1`

Answer (score 0):

```
def linearSearch(array,k):
    
    flag = False
    position = 0
    while position < len(intList) and not flag:
       
        if array[position] == k:
            flag = True
        else:
            position += 1

    return position

array = [3,5,9,7,6,12,15,9,1]
numInput = int(input("What number are you looking for? "))
numFound = linearSearch(linearList,numInput)
if numFound:
    print("The number is in index: ")
else:
    print("The number is not in the list")
```